# POWER PIVOT formula to show previous day based on weekday

Tags: powerpivot

I have two columns called

1ST column Calendar Date:

```
16/02/2015
```

2nd Column Previous Day:

```
Yes
```

Formula I am currently using:

```
if([calendar Date])=today-1,"YES","NO").
```

The 2nd column returns value based on the 1st column.

However , the problem I am getting is when I run the data on monday when we have calendar date (day on friday). So it is showing "NO" as formula only returns data for previous day.

So I want something like this
Only when I run on Monday it should give me     if([calendar Date])=today-3,"YES","NO").And all other workdays  if([calendar Date])=today-1,"YES","NO")

Can you please help me on this.

Comment: you created first formula with right syntax, why do you write second one with pseudo code? Did you tried to create a formula based on it? What was your formula, why that doesn't work?

Comment: Are you asking how to ignore weekends when getting the previous day?

Comment: .Yes,that is correct.The formula above mentioned didn't work.I also used =If([calendar Date]=WORKDAY(TODAY(),-1),"Yes","No").But this formula I am using in power pivot.Is workday() function different in power pivot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to force Friday and Saturday to be interpreted as Sunday (the day before Monday).

```
=IF(
   IF(WEEKDAY(A2) = 6,   <-- Friday
     A2 + 2,             <-- Becomes Sunday
     IF(WEEKDAY(A2) = 7, <-- Saturday
       A2 + 1,           <-- Becomes Sunday
       A2                <-- Unadjusted
     )
   ) = TODAY() - 1,
   "YES",
   "NO"
 )
```

*This formula will not work if, say, you read the report on Saturday -because as far as the formula is concerned, Saturday has 0 yesterdays and 2 tomorrows.*

**Uncommented:**
`=IF( IF(WEEKDAY(A2)= 6, A2 + 2, IF(WEEKDAY(A2) = 7, A2 + 1, A2)) = TODAY() - 1, "YES", "NO")`

Comment: The formula didn't work.I also used =If([calendar Date]=WORKDAY(TODAY(),-1),"Yes","No").But this formula I am using in power pivot

Comment: Logic is logic, the only difference should be the references: i.e. `=IF( IF(WEEKDAY([calendar Date])=6,[calendar Date]+2,IF(WEEKDAY([calendar Date])=7,[calendar Date]+1,[calendar Date]))=TODAY()-1,"YES","NO")`

Answer (score 0):

Use **WORKDAY** function for the `if`.

**WORKDAY** returns date using *start_date* and *number_of_working_days* as arguments (so skips weekends). In your case you should take [Calendar Date] as *start_date*, and *number_of_working_days* set to 1. Check if result of WORKDAY with those arguments is equal to today's date and set the cell to "YES".

Additionally you can pass holiday dates to the WORKDAY function to account also holidays as non-working days.

Put something like this in a cell:

`=IF(WORKDAY([Calendar Date];1)=TODAY();"YES";"NO")`

Comment: these formula doesn't work in power pivot.Can you please tell me other way.

Comment: @JuniorBI I updated answer, can you try with provided example.